# C# Array Output in vertical form

Tags: c#

I am using this program as an example which sort these arrays according to "b".

```
int[] a = { 5, 2, 3 }; 

int[] b = { 4, 1, 2 };

string[] c = { "John", "Peter", "Max" };

Array.Sort(b.ToArray(), c);

Array.Sort(b.ToArray(), a);

Array.Sort(b);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c));
```

The Result is:

```
2, 3, 5

1, 2, 4

Peter, Max, John
```

I want to make the result appear vertically for e.g.

```
2    1    Peter

3    2    Max

5    4    John
```

Comment: please use code tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that structure you'll need to loop and use the array indexer:

```
for(int i=0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} ", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length)
    .Select(i => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", a[i], b[i], c[i]))));
```